# How to reduce execution time of exe file

Tags: python, multithreading, pyinstaller, execution-time

I created an exe file with pyinstaller for my python script, and it performs 10 times slower, than python scrip.
I tried onedir and onefile options, but still the performance is too slow.
I need to run the script max in one second, and now it is 10 seconds (on windows).
Do you know how to reduce the execution time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No one can answer you question without a lot more information.

Comment: @martineau ,  I am using mediapipe and opencv libraries in the script. What info should i provide?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can expect that the issue is in defender. Defender will scan all .exe files while it will not intervene in python execution